# UI not updated when called within lambda

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using a [library to control Yeelight LEDs](https://github.com/roddone/YeelightAPI).
I want to add buttons to the UI dynamically/programmatically.
However, with the following snippet, no buttons are added (but I see a console print):

```
private readonly Yeelights _yee = new Yeelights();

private void btnAddMore_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    Button newBtn = new Button {Content = "A New Button"};
    splMain.Children.Add(newBtn); // button is added

    _yee.discover((o, args) => {
        Console.WriteLine(args.Device.Hostname); // it prints
        Button newBtn2 = new Button {Content = args.Device.Hostname.ToString()};
        splMain.Children.Add(newBtn2); // NO button is added
    });
}
```

The code for `discover` method:

```
public void discover(DeviceLocator.DeviceFoundEventHandler deviceFound) {
    DeviceLocator.OnDeviceFound += deviceFound;
    DeviceLocator.Discover();
}
```

The UI XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="my_lights.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="AddControls" Height="114" Width="212">
    <StackPanel Name="splMain">
        <Button Click="btnAddMore_Click">Discover</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

I suspect it has to do with the lambda scope that looses access to the UI. Or maybe with the need to force re-render.. but I'm still lost. I tried lots of things. Thanks

Comment: Try to wrap the UI related code into `Dispatcher.Invoke`

Comment: Btw. Can you explain why it's required to do that?

Comment: The OnDeviceFound event is apparently not invoked on the UI thread, which is necessary to access any UI elements. Dispatcher.Invoke or Dispatcher.BeginInvoke marshals the invocation to the UI thread.

Comment: Clemens is right. You can tell from the [source code (line 119)](https://github.com/roddone/YeelightAPI/blob/master/YeelightAPI/DeviceLocator.cs), that the event is raised on a background thread, which has no access to the UI thread. The code also shows how the thrown cross thread exception is swallowed by the library using a dirty empty `catch` block. Very bad practice. This is a good example why not to do this - especially in library code.

Comment: Also async code should always prefer the asynchronous `Task.Delay` over `Thread.Sleep`. This is not a trustworthy reliable library.

Comment: OK thanks for the tips. perhaps I'll do a PR to the library when I feel more confident in C#. Thanks!

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski - why not add an answer?

Comment: @andrew Because I've just made an assumption, without diving deeply into the mentioned library (others already did that and explained to OP everything). Also, there is a lot of existing SO questions, how to update the UI from a different thread in WPF

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the library raises the `OnDeviceFound` in a non-UI thread. If you want to manipulate the UI when the event is raised, you have to marshal it to the UI thread:

```cs
private void btnAddMore_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    Button newBtn = new Button {Content = "A New Button"};
    splMain.Children.Add(newBtn); // button is added

    _yee.discover((o, args) => {
        BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {
            Button newBtn2 = new Button {Content = args.Device.Hostname.ToString()};
            splMain.Children.Add(newBtn2); // NO button is added
        }));
    });
}
```

Additionally you should take care that an event handler will never throw an exception; you might not know how the code raising the event will cope with it.

Comment: You are right that the library's client code should handle exceptions or marshal handlers to the UI thread by itself. But in this special case, the client code never gets an exception to handle as it is catched already in the library. `catch {}` will catch _every_  exception but without handling it or rethrowing it with the original exception wrapped as inner exception.

Comment: Normally the handler of  the above code (without Dispatcher delegation) will throw a cross thread exception. But this exception is swallowed, as the client continues to execute without any exception being thrown at him. That's a problem introduced by implementation details of the library: the empty `catch` statement which stops the original exception from bubbling to the application root.

Comment: I agree on what you're saying about swallowing exceptions silently. I left my $0.02 in the related Github issue.

Comment: Thank you for your response and very open mind. I will happily pick up those $0.02 later this day. I am currently in my office and have not my GitHub credentials with me. So hope to see you later.